# Why does coef_map of the modelsummary do not display my interaction terms when i specify a name for it?

Tags: interaction, modelsummary

I have these three Models

> model <- lmer(dgentav14 ~ p95*Financial_Open_Logged + IIP_GDP + gent + loggdpt + growtht + unempt + factor(topic) + factor(wave) + (1 | country), data = data_master1, REML = FALSE)
>
> model2 <- lmer(dgentav14 ~ p05*Financial_Open_Logged + IIP_GDP + gent + loggdpt + growtht + unempt + factor(topic) + factor(wave) + (1 | country), data = data_master1, REML = FALSE)
>
> model3 <- lmer(dgentav14 ~ p50*Financial_Open_Logged + IIP_GDP + gent + loggdpt + growtht + unempt + factor(topic) + factor(wave) + (1 | country), data = data_master1, REML = FALSE)
>
> models1 = list(model, model2, model3)

When I run the original function without specifying the coef_map I do get all the variables in the model summary

[modelsummary(models1, vcov = vcov, stars = TRUE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SwfE.png)

however, once I specify the name and the order of my coefficients and get the modelsummary, the interaction Terms 'p95 × Financial_Open_Logged' are not being displayed.

> cm <- c('(Intercept)' = 'Intercept',
> 'p95' = 'Preferences of the richest 5%',
> 'p05'    = 'Preferences of the poorest 5%',
> 'p50' = 'Preferences of the median',
> 'Financial_Open_Logged' = 'Logged Financial Openness',
> 'IIP_GDP'  = 'International Investment Position',
> 'p95 × Financial_Open_Logged' = 'Preferences P95',
> 'p95*Financial_Open_Logged' = 'Preferences P95')
>
> modelsummary(models1, vcov = vcov, stars = TRUE, coef_map = cm)

[modelsummary(models1, vcov = vcov, stars = TRUE, coef_map = cm)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9i9H.png)

I have tried leaving it as 'p95 × Financial_Open_Logged' and changed it to 'p95*Financial_Open_Logged' but none of it worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

I can not tell you why, but for me it worked when I used `:` to specify the interaction terms in `cm`. So maybe try:

```
`cm <- c('(Intercept)' = 'Intercept', 'p95' = 'Preferences of the richest 5%', 'p05' = 'Preferences of the poorest 5%', 'p50' = 'Preferences of the median', 'Financial_Open_Logged' = 'Logged Financial Openness', 'IIP_GDP' = 'International Investment Position', 'p95:Financial_Open_Logged' = 'Preferences P95', 'p95:Financial_Open_Logged' = 'Preferences P95')
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation of what @flxflks wrote. The exact spelling of your coefficients can be checked using `coef(model)`.